# How to customize(? or add path to) ember.js Ember Data RESTful URI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say, I have the following code:

In app/adapters/instagram.js:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({

  urlForQueryRecord(query) {
    if (query.friendscount) {
      delete query.friendscount;
      return `${this._super(...arguments)}/friendscount`;
    }

    return this._super(...arguments);
  }

}
```

It will go out to http://localhost:20000/instagrams/friendscount to retrieve the data.

How do I make ember.js go out to "http://localhost:20000/socialnetworks/instagrams/friendscount"? (add "socialnetworks" into URI. Note that this "socialnetworks" is before the "instagrams".)

Comment: How about setting `namespace: 'socialnetworks'` in adapter.

Comment: Aha! This is the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namespace` property can be used to prefix requests with a specific url namespace.

app/adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'socialnetworks'
});
```

Refer [customizing adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/customizing-adapters/) section in ember guides